# "Вы сударь на службе?" - вопрос о запятой - нужна ли она, где она нужна, и почему

Tags: пунктуация

> 

Нужны ли запятые в предложении "Вы сударь на службе?"

Answer (score 5):

Вы, Ирина, совершенно правильно ощущаете, что тут где-то должна быть запятая.

И вы, Ирина, верно полагаете, что запятая нужна не одна:

> Вы, сударь, на службе?

Из справочника Лопатина:

> **[§ 101](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=310).** Обращение, т. е. слова и сочетания слов, называющие адресата речи, выделяется (или отделяется) запятыми. При усилении эмоциональности ставится восклицательный знак после обращения:
>   *Поздравляю, товарищи, с благополучным прибытием* (Пауст.); — *Не ходи, Володя, — проговорил Родион* (Ч.); *Откройся, мысль! Стань музыкою, слово, ударь в сердца, чтоб мир торжествовал!* (Забол.); *Я спрыгну сейчас, проводник* (Б. Паст.); *Стихни, ветер. Не лай, водяное стекло* (Ее).
>   Если после обращения имеется определение или приложение, то оно обособляется; такое определение воспринимается как второе обращение:
>   *Дедушка, миленький, где ж ты был?* (Расп.); — *Миллер, голубчик, встаньте. На берегу огни!*(Пауст.).

Предвижу ваш, сударыня, справедливый вопрос -

> Местоимение **вы** тоже называет адресата, но мы же его не обособляем:
>   "Вы, на службе?" (НЕВЕРНО)

Вот что я нашел у Розенталя ([Параграф 101: Обращения, пункт 3](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/47.htm#%D0%B7_03))   :

> Личные местоимения **ты** и **вы**, как правило, не являются обращениями, а выступают в роли подлежащего. Однако они могут входить в состав распространенного обращения, пунктуационно выделяясь вместе с ним, например: *Ну, полноте, полноте, балагур, шутник вы этакий* (Тургенев). В редких случаях местоимения **ты** и **вы** сами по себе могут выступать в роли обращения, заменяя собой название лица, к которому обращена речь; в этих случаях они выделяются запятыми (в начале и в конце предложения после них может ставиться восклицательный знак); например: *Эй, вы, чревовещатели! Марш по теплушкам!* (Вс. Иванов); *Эй, вы! Кончайте скорее!* (Достоевский); *Ты! Бери его на мушку* (Тренев); *Тише, вы!* (Антонов).

Answer (score 0):

"Вы сударь на службе?", вот так — без запятых, означает по сути: обращаются ли к вам сослуживцы подобным образом, и ошибкой такое написание не является.

Comment: Я тоже написал сначала отдельный обширный P.S. к своему ответу, поразмышляв, почему при некоторых условиях запятая не нужна - во фразах вроде "Вы кок на судне?" и т.п. - но потом счел, что это слишком нетипичный контекст для слова "сударь". ("Вы сударь на службе?" - "Нет, когда я на службе, я вагоновожатый")

Comment: Или еще можно: "Вы сударь на службе?" - "Нет, я товарищ майор на отдыхе" (0: